# Dotvvm: Route paramets get null exception for Context

Tags: c#, dotvvm

Everytime I get null exception for Context in my viewmodel:

```
 var TestId = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Parameters["Id"]);
```

In dotvvmStartup.cs I have this code:

```
config.RouteTable.Add("Default", "", "Views/index.dothtml");   
config.RouteTable.Add("TestPage", "testpage/{Id?}", "Views/testpage.dothtml");
```

When I click on route link in index.dothml:

```
<dot:RouteLink RouteName="TestPage" Text="Go!" Param-Id="1" />
```

So I got NullReferenceException for Context also I checked in Locals Context and I saw that Context had value *null*. Please, do you know what I missed?

By the way I also try modify code in dotvvmStartup.cs like you can see below but I got same result with null exception for Context:

```
config.RouteTable.Add("Default", "", "Views/index.dothtml", null);   
    config.RouteTable.Add("TestPage", "testpage/{Id?}", "Views/testpage.dothtml", new { Id = 2 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to access the `Context` property in the constructor where it's not available yet.

For now, the recommended way is to override the `Init` method and read the parameter values inside this method.

```
public override Task Init() 
{
    TestId = Convert.ToInt32(Context.Parameters["Id"]);
    return base.Init();
}
```

> In the upcoming 1.1 release of [DotVVM](https://www.dotvvm.com), we'll have parameter binding where you
>   can just declare a property in the viewmodel and use an attribute to
>   bind it to the parameter in route or query string, like this:
>
> ```
> [FromRoute("Id")]
> public int TestId { get; set; }
> ```

Comment: How is this coming?  I am having the same problem.  Also, what file do you override Task Init()?

Comment: I found my answers -- you put it in the viewModel.  You need have the threading.tasks namespace.